# Me gustaria actualizar un modelo que es creada inmediatamente despues de crear un Usuario Extendido del modelo User

Tags: django

En mi proyecto cree una extension del modelo User heredando del modelo Abstract User, a este modelo le sobreescribi el metodo save(), y exactamente despues de llamar el metodo save de la clase Padre, se crea automaticamente un instancia de un modelo llamado Perfil que contiene un campo OnetoOne con el modelo extendido de User. Me gustaria crear una vista para poder actualizar ese modelo, pero al momento de llamar el metodo save del formulario un {{form.error}} ese ejecutado, avisandome que ya existe una instancia de ese modelo con ese Usuario especificamente, lo cual esta en lo correcto porque es un campo OneToOne, no se estoy haciendo mal uso del metodo save o existe otro metodo de formularios para ejecutar una actualizacion, abajo les dejo mis intentos en esta funcion.

## Modelos

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    ROLL_CHOICES = (
        ('D', 'Doctor'),
        ('A', 'Assistant'),
    )

    SPECIALITY_CHOICES = (
        ('A&I', 'ALLERGY & IMMUNOLOGY'),
        ('A', 'ANESTHESIOLOGY'),
        ('DM', 'DERMATOLOGY'),
        ('DT', 'DENTIST'),
        ('DR', 'DIAGNOSTIC RADIOLOGY'),
        ('EM', 'EMERGENCY MEDICINE'),
        ('FM', 'FAMILY MEDICINE'),
        ('IM', 'INTERNAL MEDICINE'),
        ('MG', 'MEDICAL GENETICS'),
        ('NEU', 'NEUROLOGY'),
        ('NM', 'NUCLEAR MEDICINE'),
        ('OG', 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY'),
        ('OP', 'OPHTHALMOLOGY'),
        ('PT', 'PATHOLOGY'),
        ('PD', 'PEDIATRICS'),
        ('PMR', 'PHYSICAL MEDICINE & REHABILITATION'),
        ('PM', 'PREVENTIVE MEDICINE'),
        ('PS', 'PSYCHIATRY'),
        ('RO', 'RADIATION ONCOLOGY'),
        ('S', 'SURGERY'),
        ('U', 'UROLOGY'),
    )

    roll = models.CharField('Roll',max_length=25, blank=False, help_text='Choose the roll you will acquire in this account.', choices=ROLL_CHOICES)
    speciality = models.CharField('Speciality', max_length=100, blank=True, help_text='If your roll is (A, Assistant), leave this field blank.' , choices=SPECIALITY_CHOICES)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.first_name = self.first_name.title()
        self.last_name = self.last_name.title()
        created = not self.pk
        super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            UsersProfile.objects.create(user=self)


class UsersProfile(models.Model):

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Masculine'),
        ('F', 'Femenine'),
        ('U', 'Undefined')
    )

    LOCATION_CHOICES = (
        ('HN', 'Honduras'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='user')
    profile_pic = models.ImageField('profile picture', blank=True, null=True, help_text='Let us see you! Upload a profile picture', upload_to='accounts/profile_pictures')
    phone_number = models.CharField('phone number', max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Provide your phone number')
    bio = models.TextField('biography', blank=True, null=True, help_text='Let us know about you')
    birth_date = models.DateField('birth date', blank=True, null=True,)
    gender = models.CharField('gender', max_length=25, blank=False, null=True, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    location = models.CharField('location', max_length=100, blank=False, null=True, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, help_text='Provide your location')
    address = models.TextField('address', max_length=200, blank=False, null=True, help_text='Provide your exact address')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user']
        verbose_name = 'User Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ' ' + 'Profile Information'
```

## Formularios

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_pic = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput, required=None)
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=[x for x in range(1920, 2101)]), required=None)

    class Meta:
        model = UsersProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

## Mi Vista

```
def profile_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('main:main')
    else:
        object = get_object_or_404(UsersProfile, user=request.user)
        form = ProfileForm(instance=object)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_change.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Intenta excluir el campo `user` del form `ProfileForm`, en la clase `Meta`, el atributo `exclude`, y dime que sucede. Porque no te debería dar ningún error...

Comment: Hola @JulioCesar, ya exclui el campo de user, pero al momento de chequear mi record en el admin, todos los campos me aparecen vacios, los datos que ingrese desde el formulario no se guardan!

Comment: Cuando haces la petición POST, estas **creando una instancia** no estas actualizando ninguna instancia... si tomaste esto en cuenta?